# What is the function of the kidney in terms of osmoregulation and excretion

Tags: human-biology, kidney, osmoregulation

Also include the role that ADH plays
I am fully aware that ADH has a role in osmoregulation  but does it also play a role in exretion?

Comment: This seems like a homework question. Per the community guidelines, homework questions are off topic unless you've shown an attempt at answering the question or doing research. I suggest looking around online for information regarding ADH. Wikipedia is a pretty good start for information regarding the hormone's role in osmoregulation/excretion.